# Data not received from Bluetooth (RfcommDeviceService)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Bluetooth device which sends & receives data in serial port mode.
After successful connection to device from code:

```
var btService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(deviceInformation.Id);
streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(btService.ConnectionHostName, btService.ConnectionServiceName);
```

I send command to output stream:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
var writed = await streamSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
await streamSocket.OutputStream.FlushAsync();
```

No exceptions here. After this I listen for response:

```
IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(256);
var message = await streamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 256, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

But method `ReadAsync()` is executing infinitely.

I tried connect via DataReader/DataWriter classes, but got same result.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: No, but I think its problem with bluetooth driver (not sure) or BT api. If you can use Bluetooth LT client (bt 4.0), try it.